# Does food variety matter for villager's health in Banished?

Tags: banished

Obviously having a multitude of food sources is important in case of emergency, a worker dying, trading purposes, etc. But does the available types of food affect the villager's health?

For instance if I only provided the village with a multitude of wheat, but they had enough to eat, would their health deteriorate?

Comment: doesn't it say in game just that as one of the tips or in the tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, variety is important.

When you start the game they come with a large stock of 1 food item.  With Gatherers (Berries, Mushrooms, Roots, and Onions), Hunters (Venison) & Fishermen (Fish), your entire population will run to the Herbalist twice a year and still loose health.

With a good variety of food and good market coverage to distribute it, your population's health can max out and your Herbalists will become largely unemployed.